# portaudio / naudiodon - how to stream from PC speakers to electron application

Tags: node.js, electron, portaudio

I'm just new to portaudio and also to node.  But I found this library and sample code:
https://github.com/Streampunk/naudiodon/blob/master/scratch/inputToFile.js

I'm trying to see if I can play stream sound in an electron application.  The source of the sound will be my pc speakers.  and then .. i want to create a  object in my index.html in electron and stream the sound in.
Is this possible?

Comment: I think you need to reword your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do. Speakers can't be a sound source to an electron application, rather they are a sound output destination. In Electron you can already do a lot with audio via the native web audio api. What naudiodon/portaudio can do that Electron can't is access certain types of inputs/outputs unavailable to browser apis.